# Pdf viewer on Smartface

Tags: smartface.io

I show pdf with webview but, when pdf shows application goes to back and browser shows pdf url. I do not want to application goes to background. Is this possible to open and view pdf document on Smartface?

I tried this;

```
this.WebView1.openLinkInside = true;
this.WebView1.URL = "http://adadasd.com/adsad.pdf";
```

Answer (score 0):

it will be supported version 4.3  gonna be released 2nd week of Feb.
You can check the roadmap. 
http://www.smartface.io/roadmap/ 
General > Blob support